# Ionic 2 media plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am using the ionic plugin [cordova-plugin-media](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/media/).

`component.ts`

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

declare var Media:any;

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/settings/offline.html',
})
export class TestPage {
    audio; 
    constructor() {
        this.audio = new Media('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/Loud-Ringtone-11-Emergency-Alert.mp3?alt=media&token=7d67b437-e96b-484e-bd97-008106a06dcb');
        this.audio.play();
    }
}
```

**How am i able to play and stop the audio file?**

I am currently getting this error.

> ReferenceError: Media is not defined .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install your cordova plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-media
```

Note to test it on your phone.

You can look for full api here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

But audio.play to play, audio.stop to stop & audio.pause to pause.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply.First time only play audio file.second time audio file cannot play why..can u help me

Comment: I am getting this err. I used this.audio.stop();and this.audio.play().Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the app on device or emulator, because browser doesn't support many of the cordova plugins.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply.First time only play audio file.second time audio file cannot play why..can u help me